# Creating static files directory

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using the recent version of django. I seem to be experiencing difficulty in creating a path for my static files directory. The error I get is "TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list".

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOCAL_STATIC_CDN_PATH = [BASE_DIR / 'static_cdn_test']

STATIC_ROOT = '/static_cdn_test/blank/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles',
    '/HP/src/staticfiles',
]

MEDIA_ROOT = [BASE_DIR / 'media']
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: did you try `LOCAL_STATIC_CDN_PATH = BASE_DIR / 'static_cdn_test'` without the `[` and `]`

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder and name it **"static"** in your base directory(where you have your manage.py file) and add the following code to your settings.py file:

[image]

```
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
> 
> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>     STATIC_DIR, ]
```

[image]